# How to destructure a typescript interface and use it in another interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I'm poking around with exploring a typescript pattern and I'm not sure if it can be done.

essentially, in my React component I have the following interface:

```
interface IPaper {
  className?: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  elevation?: 'low' | 'medium' | 'high';
}
```

while the above example is fine, I want to explore something smarter and easier to maintain. Specifically, using the keys currently found in the `ThemeParameters` example shown below:

```
  interface ThemeParameters extends StorybookIntegration {
    ...
    
    elevation: {
      low: string;
      medium: string;
      high: string;
    };
  
    ...
  }
```

In practice my component would look something like the example below with the component's `elevation` property being coupled to whatever the elevation setup is like in my `ThemeParameters`. That way, if I ever modify my theme it will be automatically captured by the interface on the component.

```
interface IPaper {
  className?: string;
  children: React.ReactNode;
  elevation?: ThemeParameters['elevation'];
}

const Paper = ({ className, children, ...props }: IPaper): JSX.Element => (
  <Wrapper className={className} elevation="low" {...props}>
    {children}
  </Wrapper>
);

const Wrapper = styled.div<{ elevation: string }>`
  box-shadow: ${({ theme, elevation }) => theme.elevation[elevation]};
`;
```

Unfortunately, this isnt exactly working. Any clever ideas with how I can set this up using typescript?

---

#### SOLUTION

example using the suggestion from the best answer below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ThemeParameters['elevation']
```

is this type:

```
{
  low: string;
  medium: string;
  high: string;
}
```

---

So you want the keys of that of object. That's what `keyof` is for:

```
keyof ThemeParameters['elevation']
```

Which is this type:

```
'low' | 'medium' | 'high'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTgA7GJKTdJOASQAUUxa4BvUuONADYoAzsIByKEEgD8ALjjCYUKgHMA3L34ALYAIAmRSvOToYAOhMYxEPUg18kApADcUMYBEpy4AayQBPCEw4ABUtJCk2KEkkGihhAG18Rxc3D0p8AF0NAF9yKjj6NEYwiKQomLjhbk0U13dPeR4+PgEIAHd5RWVKdU0+KT1gAFcQLqVVexadFS1xnr6+HNzyNE9FOBpFeVZ2TgBeGr5BEXEY+XwQpEV8ABpNNB19Q3kAHgA+TAgIV4B6d-uDic9XSFza7TupDypDWlA2WxgADEULodmwOFA4IdmvwhKIJFILlcboDtLoDEgjHAPl8fv9SXU0o0CJQIApho84IyGhlbnBfr9Nv4OFyoDgoFCgA)